# How to read query param in WSO2 ESB 4.8 or above?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a rest end point in WSO2ESB (4.8),I need to read query parameter to set as dynamic payload  as the my business  ,But i failed to read it due to newer with wso2 ESB.Any help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bellow code may help you

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sample" context="/api/sample">
   <resource methods="OPTIONS GET" uri-template="/{val1}/groups/{val2}.json?q1={v1}&q2={v2}">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="uri.var.q1" expression="$url:q1"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.q2" expression="$url:q2"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.val1" expression="get-property('uri.var.val1')"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.val2" expression="get-property('uri.var.val2')"></property>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http method="GET" uri-template=""></http>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send></send>
  </outSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: this gives: Caused by: org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: Variable url

Answer (score 7):

Define a REST API inside ESB and access to query params with get-property('query.param.xxx') or get-property('uri.var.yyy'), sample :

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/testwso2/{symbol}?arg1={value1}">

get-property('query.param.arg1')
get-property('uri.var.symbol')
```

Comment: For further reference check http://asitha.github.io/cs/programming/wso2/esb/mediators/2017/08/14/get-query-params-with-wso2-esb/