# How to read request parameter values in wso2 esb script mediator

Tags: wso2, url-parameters, wso2-esb

I need to catch the url parameters parsing in a get request by script mediator. I uses WSO2 esb 4.8.1. and I tried with the following js code. but it gives an error saying window is not defined.

```js
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}

   
  var requestNew="<m:ViW xmlns:m=\"wom\">                                                                                                   
   <m:request>
   <RequestHeader>
               <RemoteIP>dummyIp</RemoteIP>
               <AppName>dummyAppName</AppName>
               <AppPassword>dummyPassword</AppPassword>
               <UserName>dummyUserName</UserName>
            </RequestHeader>
            <OrderId>23</OrderId>
            <AccountNo>23</AccountNo>
            <Cir>23</Cir>
            <DocketNo>23</DocketNo>
            <Status>23</Status>
            <RequestType>23</RequestType>
            <RequestedFrom>2016-04-19T22:47:37.000Z</RequestedFrom>";
   requestNew=requestNew+"
            <RequestedTo>"+getUrlVars()['RequestedTo']+"</RequestedTo>
         </m:request>                                                                     
      </m:ViW>";
   
   
   mc.setPayloadXML(new XML(requestNew));
```

So how can I access url parameter values in the wso2 esb script mediator?

Comment: What do you mean by url parameter? Rest url template values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read query param in WSO2 ESB 4.8 or above?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295902/how-to-read-query-param-in-wso2-esb-4-8-or-above)

Comment: that also somewhat same. my case is accessing querry parameters inside script mediator. I couldnt access in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Following](http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/retrieving-rest-parameters-in-javascript-api-prototypes/) blog will tell you how to do it. Its written targetting [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/). But since synapse is used in both ESB and API Manager, its valid for your question as well. In summary,

To retrieve path parameters

```
var id = mc.getProperty('uri.var.id');
```

To retrieve query parameters

```
var mask = mc.getProperty('query.param.mask');
```