# Question about GET API Methods using wso2

Tags: java, wso2

I have question about how to create API GET method in `wso2` ? and
this is what I have to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/request" name="Request" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence/>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

My question is how to create and read the parameter from API GET METHODS using `wso2`?

For example like

If I need to http://localhost:8280/request?vtid=1278$token=1234

how to create the api? and how to read value from parameter vtid and token ? using `wso2`?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295902/how-to-read-query-param-in-wso2-esb-4-8-or-above):

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/testwso2/{symbol}?arg1={value1}">

get-property('query.param.arg1')
get-property('uri.var.symbol')
```

Notice that the URL of your API already accounts for the amount of parameters you need.

NOTE: I know this is an older version of WSO2 but this functionality I think did not change.